# use of neutral line in power distribution?

Tags: mains

**Neutral Line** - what is the propose of this line ?.

In-case Neutral line failure power will be lose ?

In power Distribution We are using Line (phase) for input ~240V, In after usage or cycle, What happens the energy ?. its will complete cycle ?

> ==> Line P  ---------->240V --- >
>
> ==> Neutral N -- 0 -->

Or energy will be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every power distribution scheme requires a complete circuit.  That includes at least two wires.

There is no reason to name the actual wires except to standardize on things such as safety.  In most AC distribution systems, the neutral is bonded to a local earth ground.

So, the neutral, in a distribution system is the return path for the phase current, and is typically bonded to ground.

If the neutral is lost, no current can flow, so yes, you effectively lose power.

What happens to what energy? If you feed power to a light bulb, energy is converted to heat and light.  If you feed power to a motor, energy is converted to motion.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too basic for this site.

See [Hot, Neutral, and Ground Wires](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/alternating-current-in-electronics-hot-neutral-and.html) for an introduction and search the web for other tutorials.